# Is “taper fort” or “taper si fort” an idiom?

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques

> Mais fallait-il vraiment **taper si fort**?

Literally, *taper [si] fort* could be translated into English as *hitting / knocking that hard*.
But idiomatically, should *taper [si] fort* be indeed an idiomatic expression, it should mean something like *to exaggerate / to make too much of (something)*. Thus, the question should be rendered in English as *Was it really necessary for us to exaggerate so much?*

Am I correct or not?

A fuller [context](http://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2013/03/04/chers-amis-cette-fois-vous-avez-fait-fort_1842407_3232.html) of this:

> Mais vous, vous avez bien failli élire le premier pour une quatrième fois (il s'en est fallu de 150 000 voix à la Chambre), vous avez éliminé l'économiste qui, il est vrai, vous avait assommés d'impôts, et vous avez probablement empêché le social-démocrate de devenir un jour président du conseil. En donnant 8,5 millions de suffrages à l'ex-comique et en lui permettant de bloquer le Sénat, donc le pays, vous avez fait sauter la banque.
>
> (…) Ces experts ont écouté vos plaintes sur la corruption, sur la “caste
> des élus” et ses privilèges. (…) J’ai perçu le
> malaise. Mais fallait-il vraiment taper si fort?

Comment: "*frapper fort*" is an idiomatic expression which mean "do something big (that will have a big impact)". "tapper fort" is much less common...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Taper fort* isn't really an idiom, it is a natural derivation from an abstract meaning of *taper*. *Taper* means to hit, as does *frapper*, but there are different nuances in these two words. *Taper fort* is “*hit hard*” (subject to nuances), “*taper si fort*” is “hit so hard”.

In the context of a speech, *taper sur quelqu'un* (or sometimes *taper sur une idée*) means to argue vehemently against a person (or sometimes an idea). It implies that the discourse was not only opposed to this person, but expounded on the opposition at some length, possibly with exaggeration. There is however no implication of violence, dishonesty or inappropriate speech.

*Taper fort* insists on the way the idea was conveyed, not just on the idea itself. The author of the passage you cite implicitly concedes that he agrees with the core issue (that the “plaintes sur la corruption …” are founded), but disagrees that the speaker should have been so vehement in their expression.

To expand a bit more on the context: the author is addressing the Italian people after Italian elections. The means of expression was the votes in the election. The author agrees with the Italians' discontent but disapproves of the extent to which they voted against the parties who were in power.

Here *taper* takes on another meaning, which is to hit something precisely. For example, *taper dans le mille* means to hit a target dead center (in the small central circle that awards 1000 points). The Italians have “*tapé sur*” the traditional political parties — they reduced these parties' power. *Frapper sur* would not work as it implies physical violence. (*Frapper sur* can also imply a physical act without violence, as in “*frapper du poing sur la table*” — hit the table with one's fist to attract attention, often used metaphorically. But if a target is designated, *frapper sur* implies a physical act against the target.)

Comment: Look for occurrences of “ils ont frappé fort”, I bet 95% of them don't refer to any kind of physical violence. It's used figuratively. *Taper fort* is then a mix of *taper sur* and this figurative use found in *frapper fort*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez « Frappé fort », oui. Mais pas « frappé sur … ». Ici, le contexte implique que les Italiens ont tapé sur la gauche et le centre en votant Grillo (il faut regarder un peu plus que la partie de l'article citée dans la question pour comprendre).

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse.

Comment: @Gilles So _taper sur qn_ means _to run sb down_; or _to criticize_, doesn't it?

Comment: @indoxica It's more than *criticize*. *Run down* is close, but *taper sur* is a bit more general: you can use *taper sur* without running the person into the ground, if you're arguing vehemently about one specific idea.

Comment: J'ai édité, ça me convient si tu parles de *frapper sur*.

Answer (score 4):

Your context is not long enough for me to be sure, as the proper idiomatic expression is "frapper fort". Moreover "Mais fallait-il vraiment taper si fort?" is questioning if the reaction is exaggerated or not, whereas your English translation states that it is and questions the necessity. The difference is subtle but your translation is assertive (I would say "péremptoire" in French), whereas it is finely-shaded in French. Maybe something like   “Didn't you overreact?” (as suggested by Stéphane Gimenez) is closer to the author's feelings.

Comment: So I was pretty close to saying it like it is, wasn't I?

Comment: Yes indeed you've understood correctly the meaning, I just find your translation a bit harsh. I always tend to quibble about French :)

Comment: I also lack some more context, but it seems to me that the question is actually “fallait-il que *vous* tapiez si fort ?”, which I would render in English as “didn't you overreact?”. (Notice the negative.)

Comment: Indeed Stéphane, you translation seems much better. Editing.

Comment: So, if this is an actual idiom (which I couldn't have known since there is no such construction in my dictionary), which of the versions I have already given is the idiom? Is it with _si_? Is it without _si_? As to how the question actually is, it is precisely the way I have quoted it because it is a quotation from an article I read a few months ago. So far, the only thing established is my semantic closeness to the original intention in the quoted question, as already asserted by FredericS. So the only thing that is yet to be established is whether this idiom has a _si_ in it or not.

Comment: @indoxica: “frapper fort” is kind of semi-idiomatic, it's most often used with a figurative meaning (nothing was actually hit, but it looks like it). Adding a “si” is a natural extension that follows standard grammatical rules. (Just like “hit so hard” can be obtained from “hit hard”.)

Comment: Then why didn't the author of that article use _frapper fort_? Why did he use _taper fort_, when this is not an established idiom? Any explanation for that, please?

Comment: *Taper* is just a slight variation which actually fits better in this context.